# Is it ok to post a clone of a famous game up for review or in a website?

Tags: copyright

I recently wrote a clone of the famous Jeopardy! game. It is copyrighted but I believe that if I my copy was made for educational and recreational uses only (no commercial) it falls under FAIR USE, am I right? If so, can I publish it on the public internet?

I am using the main screen and concept of a game, the name is the same, and the audience will just be me and the code reviewers. I am in the EU. (Something like 10 people will play the game so might it count as private use?)